# Quill JS Modules Not Working in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, quill

I am making an app using Quill JS and Electron. I want to use Quill's syntax highlighting module and followed the instructions on the API page (https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/syntax/). For some reason, the function does not work (no highlighting is shown in code-block). I switched the `<script src=...>` tag to `require` and declared Quill as

```
quill = new Quill('#editor', {
modules: {
    syntax: require('highlight.js'),
    toolbar: false
},
theme: 'snow'
```

});

The result is whenever I type something into the code-block, an error saying " " is not a valid language. I made sure that I included the css file on the main page. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From the link that you provide. It clearly says

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
                  modules: {
                  syntax: true,              // Include syntax module
                  toolbar: [['code-block']]  // Include button in toolbar
               },
               theme: 'snow'
            });
```

So you only need to set true on that property.
What you have to be careful is to make sure window.hljs is present if you include the script tag before Quill is imported.

Or if you use webpack. You can use ProvidePlugin and set it like this

```
plugins : [
    .
    . 
    new ProvidePlugin({
        'window.Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js',
        'Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js',
        "window.hljs": "highlight.js"
    })
]
```